# React js says Cannot read property 'name' of undefined when calling json files

Tags: reactjs

I need to call json file externally in reactjs. Can someone test this code with me. Reactjs says error **Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**. it seems its not seeing the name column in the json file. can someone help me fix the problem. Thanks

**data.json**

```
[{"name":"fred","description":"first"},{"name":"tony","description":"second"}]
```

below is the entire code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.0.1/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.0.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>


</head>




<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">


const ReactScrollPagination = React.createClass({
  isolate: {
    onePageHeight: null,
    timeoutFunc: null,
    excludeHeight: null,
    defaultShowTime: 2000
  },
  pageDivStle: {
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: '15px',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  pageContentStyle: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    background: 'rgba(6, 6, 6, 0.54)',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    padding: '3px 15px',
    minWidth: '80px',
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: '0 auto',
    opacity: 1,
    WebkitTransition: 'opacity 0.8s',
    MozTransition: 'opacity 0.8s',
    OTransition: 'opacity 0.8s',
    transition: 'opacity 0.8s'
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      currentPage: 1,
      totalPages: null,
      showPageStatus: false
    }
  },
  showPageDiv: function () {
    if (this.isolate.timeoutFunc) {
      clearTimeout(this.isolate.timeoutFunc)
    }
    this.setState({showPageStatus: true})
    let showTime = this.props.paginationShowTime ? parseInt(this.props.paginationShowTime)
    : this.isolate.defaultShowTime

    this.isolate.timeoutFunc = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({showPageStatus: false})
    }, showTime)
  },
  getExcludeHeight: function () {
    if (this.isolate.excludeHeight !== null) {
      return this.isolate.excludeHeight
    }

    let excludeHeight = 0

    if (this.props.excludeHeight) {
      let propsExcludeHeight = parseInt(this.props.excludeHeight)
      if (isNaN(propsExcludeHeight)) {
        console.error('WARN: Failed to convert the props excludeHeight "' + this.props.excludeHeight +
          '" to Number, please verify. Will take "0" by default.')
      } else {
        excludeHeight = propsExcludeHeight
      }
    } else if (this.props.excludeElement && typeof this.props.excludeElement === 'string') {
      let excludeEle = jQuery(this.props.excludeElement)

      if (excludeEle.size() === 0) {
        console.error('WARN: Failed to get the element with given selectdor "' + this.props.excludeElement +
          '", please veirify. Will take "0" by default.')
      } else {
        excludeHeight = excludeEle.height()
      }
    }
    this.isolate.excludeHeight = excludeHeight

    return excludeHeight
  },
  initialOnePageHeight: function () {
    const documentHeight = jQuery(document).height()

    if (typeof this.props.totalPages === 'number' && this.props.totalPages > 0 && this.isolate.onePageHeight === null) {
      let excludeHeight = this.getExcludeHeight()
      this.isolate.onePageHeight = documentHeight - excludeHeight
    }
  },
  handlePageValue: function () {

    this.initialOnePageHeight()

    let windowHeight = jQuery(window).height()
    let scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight - this.getExcludeHeight()

    if (this.isolate.onePageHeight !== null) {
      let currentPage = Math.ceil(scrollTop / this.isolate.onePageHeight) || 1
      this.setState({currentPage: currentPage})
      this.showPageDiv()
    }
  },
  scrollHanlder: function () {
    let documentHeight = jQuery(document).height()

    let windowHeight = jQuery(window).height()
    let scrollBottom = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight

    if ((scrollBottom + 30) >= documentHeight) {
      this.props.fetchFunc()
    }
    this.handlePageValue()
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    jQuery(window).unbind('scroll', this.scrollHanlder)
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
    jQuery(window).scroll(this.scrollHanlder)
  },

  render: function () {
    let acutalPageContentDivStyle = jQuery.extend({}, this.props.innerDivStyle || this.pageContentStyle)

    if (!this.state.showPageStatus) {
      acutalPageContentDivStyle.opacity = 0
    }

    // let actualDiv = this.state.showPageStatus ? withPageDiv : null
    return (
      <div style={this.props.outterDivStyle || this.pageDivStle} >
        <div style={acutalPageContentDivStyle} >
          <span >
            {this.state.currentPage}
          </span>
          /
          <span >
            {this.props.totalPages || 1}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

// pagination ends


// THE REAL CODE
const Item = React.createClass({
  itemStyle: {
     overflow: 'hidden',
     background: '#fff',
     padding: '7px 15px 8px',
     color: '#777',
     lineHeight: '1.5',
     fontSize: '12px',
     fontFamily: 'PingFangSC-Light, Roboto, sans-serif, Helvetica',
     borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc'
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: '14px',
    color: '#333'
  },
  indexStyle: {
    color: '#5cb85c',
    fontSize: '20px',
    float: 'left'
  },
    render: function () {
    return (
        <div style={this.itemStyle} >
        <div style={this.indexStyle} >
            {this.props.index + 1}
        </div>
        <div style={{float: 'left', paddingLeft: '5px'}} >
          <div style={this.titleStyle} > 
            {this.props.name} 
          </div>
          <div >
            {this.props.description}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const List = React.createClass({
  isolate: {
    pageNo: 0,
    isRequesting: false,
    totalPages: 0
  },
    getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      totalPages: 0,
      list: []
    }
  },
  generateList: function () {
    let result = []
    for (let i = 0; i< 15; i++) {
            result.push({
            name: 'Item Name',
            description: 'Scroll DOWN to load next page, and UP to see current position.'
          })
        }
    return result
  },
  getNextPage: function () {
    let self = this
    if (this.isolate.isRequesting || (this.isolate.pageNo > 0 && this.isolate.pageNo >= this.isolate.totalPages)) {

      return
    }
    this.isolate.pageNo ++
    this.isolate.isRequesting = true
   let jqXhr = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'data.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        pageNo: this.isolate.pageNo,
        json: JSON.stringify({
            totalPages: 5,
          list: this.generateList()
        }),
        delay: 0.1
      }
    })

    jqXhr.done((result) => {
        this.isolate.isRequesting = false
        this.isolate.totalPages = result.totalPages
        let newList = this.state.list.concat(result.list)
        this.setState({
            totalPages: result.totalPages,
            list: newList
        })
    })

    jqXhr.fail((reason) => {
       this.isolate.isRequesting = false
       this.isolate.pageNo --
       console.error('Loading next page failed')
    })
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
      this.getNextPage()
  },
  render: function () {
    let listItemDiv = this.state.list.map((obj, index) => {
        return (
        <Item 
            name={obj.name}
          description={obj.description}
          index={index}
          key={index}
        />
      )
    })

    return (
        <div >
        {listItemDiv}
        <ReactScrollPagination
            fetchFunc={this.getNextPage}
          totalPages={this.state.totalPages}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const APP = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <List />;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <APP />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**The error is showing within the reactjs rendering propertise**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result itself containing json data. So no need to call it as `let newList = this.state.list.concat(result.list)`. Just change it to `let newList = this.state.list.concat(result)`

```
jqXhr.done((result) => {
    this.isolate.isRequesting = false
    this.isolate.totalPages = result.totalPages
    let newList = this.state.list.concat(result)
    this.setState({
        totalPages: result.totalPages,
        list: newList
    })
})
```

See the working code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.0.1/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.0.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>


</head>




<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">


const ReactScrollPagination = React.createClass({
  isolate: {
    onePageHeight: null,
    timeoutFunc: null,
    excludeHeight: null,
    defaultShowTime: 2000
  },
  pageDivStle: {
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: '15px',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  pageContentStyle: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    background: 'rgba(6, 6, 6, 0.54)',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    padding: '3px 15px',
    minWidth: '80px',
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: '0 auto',
    opacity: 1,
    WebkitTransition: 'opacity 0.8s',
    MozTransition: 'opacity 0.8s',
    OTransition: 'opacity 0.8s',
    transition: 'opacity 0.8s'
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      currentPage: 1,
      totalPages: null,
      showPageStatus: false
    }
  },
  showPageDiv: function () {
    if (this.isolate.timeoutFunc) {
      clearTimeout(this.isolate.timeoutFunc)
    }
    this.setState({showPageStatus: true})
    let showTime = this.props.paginationShowTime ? parseInt(this.props.paginationShowTime)
    : this.isolate.defaultShowTime

    this.isolate.timeoutFunc = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({showPageStatus: false})
    }, showTime)
  },
  getExcludeHeight: function () {
    if (this.isolate.excludeHeight !== null) {
      return this.isolate.excludeHeight
    }

    let excludeHeight = 0

    if (this.props.excludeHeight) {
      let propsExcludeHeight = parseInt(this.props.excludeHeight)
      if (isNaN(propsExcludeHeight)) {
        console.error('WARN: Failed to convert the props excludeHeight "' + this.props.excludeHeight +
          '" to Number, please verify. Will take "0" by default.')
      } else {
        excludeHeight = propsExcludeHeight
      }
    } else if (this.props.excludeElement && typeof this.props.excludeElement === 'string') {
      let excludeEle = jQuery(this.props.excludeElement)

      if (excludeEle.size() === 0) {
        console.error('WARN: Failed to get the element with given selectdor "' + this.props.excludeElement +
          '", please veirify. Will take "0" by default.')
      } else {
        excludeHeight = excludeEle.height()
      }
    }
    this.isolate.excludeHeight = excludeHeight

    return excludeHeight
  },
  initialOnePageHeight: function () {
    const documentHeight = jQuery(document).height()

    if (typeof this.props.totalPages === 'number' && this.props.totalPages > 0 && this.isolate.onePageHeight === null) {
      let excludeHeight = this.getExcludeHeight()
      this.isolate.onePageHeight = documentHeight - excludeHeight
    }
  },
  handlePageValue: function () {

    this.initialOnePageHeight()

    let windowHeight = jQuery(window).height()
    let scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight - this.getExcludeHeight()

    if (this.isolate.onePageHeight !== null) {
      let currentPage = Math.ceil(scrollTop / this.isolate.onePageHeight) || 1
      this.setState({currentPage: currentPage})
      this.showPageDiv()
    }
  },
  scrollHanlder: function () {
    let documentHeight = jQuery(document).height()

    let windowHeight = jQuery(window).height()
    let scrollBottom = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight

    if ((scrollBottom + 30) >= documentHeight) {
      this.props.fetchFunc()
    }
    this.handlePageValue()
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    jQuery(window).unbind('scroll', this.scrollHanlder)
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
    jQuery(window).scroll(this.scrollHanlder)
  },

  render: function () {
    let acutalPageContentDivStyle = jQuery.extend({}, this.props.innerDivStyle || this.pageContentStyle)

    if (!this.state.showPageStatus) {
      acutalPageContentDivStyle.opacity = 0
    }

    // let actualDiv = this.state.showPageStatus ? withPageDiv : null
    return (
      <div style={this.props.outterDivStyle || this.pageDivStle} >
        <div style={acutalPageContentDivStyle} >
          <span >
            {this.state.currentPage}
          </span>
          /
          <span >
            {this.props.totalPages || 1}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

// pagination ends


// THE REAL CODE
const Item = React.createClass({
  itemStyle: {
     overflow: 'hidden',
     background: '#fff',
     padding: '7px 15px 8px',
     color: '#777',
     lineHeight: '1.5',
     fontSize: '12px',
     fontFamily: 'PingFangSC-Light, Roboto, sans-serif, Helvetica',
     borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc'
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: '14px',
    color: '#333'
  },
  indexStyle: {
    color: '#5cb85c',
    fontSize: '20px',
    float: 'left'
  },
    render: function () {
    return (
        <div style={this.itemStyle} >
        <div style={this.indexStyle} >
            {this.props.index + 1}
        </div>
        <div style={{float: 'left', paddingLeft: '5px'}} >
          <div style={this.titleStyle} > 
            {this.props.name} 
          </div>
          <div >
            {this.props.description}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const List = React.createClass({
  isolate: {
    pageNo: 0,
    isRequesting: false,
    totalPages: 0
  },
    getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      totalPages: 0,
      list: []
    }
  },
  generateList: function () {
    let result = []
    for (let i = 0; i< 15; i++) {
            result.push({
            name: 'Item Name',
            description: 'Scroll DOWN to load next page, and UP to see current position.'
          })
        }
    return result
  },
  getNextPage: function () {
    let self = this
    if (this.isolate.isRequesting || (this.isolate.pageNo > 0 && this.isolate.pageNo >= this.isolate.totalPages)) {

      return
    }
    this.isolate.pageNo ++
    this.isolate.isRequesting = true
   let jqXhr = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'data.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        pageNo: this.isolate.pageNo,
        json: JSON.stringify({
            totalPages: 5,
          list: this.generateList()
        }),
        delay: 0.1
      }
    })

    jqXhr.done((result) => {
        this.isolate.isRequesting = false
        this.isolate.totalPages = result.totalPages
        let newList = this.state.list.concat(result)
        this.setState({
            totalPages: result.totalPages,
            list: newList
        })
    })

    jqXhr.fail((reason) => {
       this.isolate.isRequesting = false
       this.isolate.pageNo --
       console.error('Loading next page failed')
    })
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
      this.getNextPage()
  },
  render: function () {
  console.log(this.state.list);
    let listItemDiv = this.state.list.map((obj, index) => {
        return (
        <Item 
            name={obj.name}
          description={obj.description}
          index={index}
          key={index}
        />
      )
    })

    return (
        <div >
        {listItemDiv}
        <ReactScrollPagination
            fetchFunc={this.getNextPage}
          totalPages={this.state.totalPages}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const APP = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <List />;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <APP />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an issue with accessing keys in particular indices in the array. Try this render function:

```
render: function () {
    let listItemDiv = this.state.list.map((obj, index) => {
        return (
        <Item 
            name={obj[index].name}
          description={obj.description}
          index={index}
          key={index}
        />
      )
    })
```

Comment: Hello Dear, within the render by using your code it says error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"